# using loc(index) on pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think I miss something very basic in the Pandas DataFrame:

I have the following program:

---

```
array = {'A':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'B':[5, 6, 7, 8]}
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(
    [   '09:30',
        '09:31',
        '09:32',
        '09:33'     ])
data = pd.DataFrame(array, index=index)
data.index = data.index.strftime('%H:%M')
         
print(data)
print(data.loc('09:33'))
```

---

I get:

```
       A  B
09:30  1  5
09:31  2  6
09:32  3  7
09:33  4  8
```

Which is great, but I can not access a row using it's index '09:33' and I get:

```
ValueError: No axis named 09:33 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

What am I missing ?

Thank you,
Ehood

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets `[]` instead: `data.loc['09:33']`

```py
array = {'A':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'B':[5, 6, 7, 8]}
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(
    [   '09:30',
        '09:31',
        '09:32',
        '09:33'     ])
data = pd.DataFrame(array, index=index)
data.index = data.index.strftime('%H:%M')
         
print(data)
print(data.loc['09:33'])  # HERE!
```

Output:

```py
       A  B
09:30  1  5
09:31  2  6
09:32  3  7
09:33  4  8
A    4
B    8
Name: 09:33, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. When using loc or iloc, its followed by square brackets, like this:

`df.loc['viper']`

In your case that ends up like this:

[image]

You can find the documentation for that [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).